# How to change cordova version in IBM Worklight project

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

In Worklight I need to use some Cordova plugins to access some native features in Android. As I see Worklight takes up the latest version of Cordova i.e 2.7. But in Cordova 2.7 there is so many stupid changes like for plugins they have changed the execute method completely. This seems ridiculous as the existing Plugins on Github is not working in cordova 2.7 projects. All plugins need to be changed as per 2.7, who is going to do that !

Anyways, is there any option in Worklight Studio to use specific cordova as per requirement ?

Comment: If your question is answered, please mark it as Answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worklight does not use Cordova 2.7.
In Worklight 5.0.6 Cordova 2.3 is used and in a near-future release of Worklight Cordova will be upgraded to 2.6.

In any case, you cannot independently replace the Cordova version used in Worklight. I mean you can try, but this method is not supported by IBM (and there is no need to in this case because 2.7 is not used).

Comment: Just got an email from Google Play Developer Support; to upgrade my free WL5.0.6 based Apps to Cordova v3.5.1+ due to security vulnerabilities. I know the latest WL 6.2 comes with Cordova v3.4.1. Now I have to upgrade my Apps before they get removed. In order to change Cordova plugin, do you suggest anything to keep in mind or consider?

Comment: Sure. Test the app and make sure everything works before submitting.